# Azure: How to map user login to database?

Tags: sql, database, azure

I have an Azure SQL login. I need to map this account to two databases. How can this be done?

- I have access to Azure Portal
- I'm connected to the DB server in SSMS

Comment: What do you mean by "Azure user login"? Or "map this account"? Do you mean to say "Azure SQL Login" instead? Just use SSMS.

Comment: @dai yes SQL login. Map user to a database so the user has login access to the database